# WSL starting in /mnt/c/windows/system32

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2

I installed WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 (21H2 Build 19044.1766) a while back now, but I haven't had a use for it until now.

When I start WSL, I wind up in `/mnt/c/windows/system32` rather than a home directory.   I've googled why this might happen and can't find anything.  As I only use WSL2 and VSCode together for writing code, and I have a code directory in my Dropbox, I would ideally like to have this code directory be a folder below my home directory, but still in my Dropbox.  I lost my house in the Colorado Marshall Wildfire in December, but I didn't lose any data as everything is in my Dropbox so that's where I would like to keep it.

Anyway, the first step is why is WSL throwing me into the Windows' system directory?  How can I change this?

Then, any ideas on how I can get this to use my Dropbox directories?  I am happy to create a user directory and then put the code directory under it, but within the Dropbox so it is backed out to the cloud.

However, if this is going to cause issues, then I would probably script something to back it up to Dropbox I guess.

Comment: Are you launching wsl as an administrator?  As in.. from the windows side?  System32 is the default home directory for windows' administrator account.  If not.. instead of solving the problem and knowing why, fix your `.bashrc` to put you wherever you want.

Comment: I forgot to add, I am NOT starting it as administrator... I know system32 is default when you runas administrator and that would make sense.  So, I would expect my .bashrc to be in my home directory... you see my problem?

Comment: I do indeed see your problem. ;^) .. I was thinking that you could either figure out why it is happening via your .bashrc OR perhaps workaround the (stupid) problem by setting the working directory by hand in there.  Have you tried a blank .bashrc (just to test of course).. also /etc/profiles and /etc/bashrc

Comment: ok, so, I am new to wsl2... the /mnt/c/windows/systeme32 confused me.  There is a /home/<myuserid>  and in there is a .bashrc  so thats fine.  $HOME show me that my home is /home/<myuserid> so thats fine.  When I type cd, it puts my in my /home/,myuserid> directory.  so that all seems fine.  Its just when I start wsl2 that it puts me in the windows system directory.  /etc/passwd also lists my home as /home/,myuserid.  I can live with this I guess, now its just a curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is WSL throwing me into the Windows' system directory?

By default, WSL starts in the current working directory of its parent process.  This can vary by starting method.  For instance, for me on Windows 11:

- Typing `wsl.exe` into the Start menu (via <kbd>Win</kbd>) results in being in the System32 directory as in your case.
- However, starting from the Windows "Run" dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), results in starting in my *Windows* user profile folder (i.e. `/mnt/c/Users/ntd`).

> How can I change this?

The recommended way to change this is via the `--cd` argument on the command-line of the `wsl.exe` command that you use to launch.  E.g.:

```
wsl.exe --cd "C:\Users\username\Dropbox\path\to\folder"
```

While you could also change it in something like `~/.bashrc`, this isn't recommend as it can interfere with other applications in WSL.

It's also possible to have WSL start directly in your Ubuntu home directory using:

```
wsl ~
```

Note that the `~` does need to be the first argument to WSL.

> any ideas on how I can get this to use my Dropbox directories? I am happy to create a user directory and then put the code directory under it ...

In general, you don't want to put the WSL/Linux home directory itself on a non-WSL (native Linux) filesystem.  It will ultimately cause issues with:

- Permissions, which can be overcome with `/etc/wsl.conf` settings.
- Ownership, which can also be overcome with the same
- Performance, which cannot be overcome
- File locking behavior differences between Linux and Windows/Dropbox, which also cannot be overcome.

If you are developing in WSL2, Microsoft recommends that you place any files inside the virtual filesystem itself, rather than on a Windows or networked drive.

I would recommend pursuing the "script a backup" solution personally.  A simple `rsync` can probably suffice, assuming the Dropbox folder is accessing through the 9P file share that WSL creates for Windows files/directories/drives.

Comment: good stuff.  I figured there might be a problem putting $HOME on a windows filesystem.  I am/was using the penguin icon in windows start menue to start wsl2.  I have since noticed that there is a Ubuntu On WIindows app.  This starts wsl2 (I guess) and puts me in my home directory.  This is an app, I can't actually see what .exe it is running or what it is doing, perhaps starting wsl.exe with the parameters cd that you describe.  Anyway, thanks, I think I am good now.  Appreciate the input.